# Problems with Universal iPhone/ipad app build

Tags: iphone

I have created a Universal (iPhone/ipad) application .I have created separate Xib designs for iPhone and iPad both works well. When i build the app it should give a single .APP(build).I installed in iPhone and iPad tested correctly.

Now i want to give a two separate builds (for user to test), one for iPhone and another one for iPad.So in project settings i changed a target device family (iPhone/ipad -> into iPhone) and (iPhone/ipad -> into iPad). So it gives two separate builds.One for iPhone and another one for iPad.

My problem is when i build with iPhone(as target device family) and installed in iPad means it loads a iPad design not an iPhone design.What could be the mistake i did here ? I search a lot and could not find any solution.

If any one did like this? or do it for me?(testing)

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Why give two separate builds? The point of a universal app is that the same build works on both devices. Why not test the build you are going to release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` if you run iPhone-designed app on iPad. And thats why iPad version of xib file is selected. So you need to attach correct .xib file manually, or exclude iPad version of it from iPhone resources.

Comment: you are correct .Changed the xib file name will do the trick.thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tester can install the same build in both iPhone and iPad. The concept of universal build is that, the same app will work on both iPad and iPhone.